# Can we implement a max or min macro, which can take variable arguments (more than two parameters )

Tags: c++, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

I want to implement a new max/min macro, which can take more than two parameter, for example:

```
#define max( ... ) ...
```

and then, I can use it like this:

```
max( p0, p1, p2, p3 )
max( 2, 4, 100 )
max( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ) -> 7
```

if this macro can help us to implement that macro?

```
#define PP_EXPAND(X) X
#define PP_ARG_COUNT(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(__VA_ARGS__, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0))
#define PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, N, ...) N

#define PP_ARG_AT(Index, ...) PP_ARG_AT_##Index(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_ARG_AT_0(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_1(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_2(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_3(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_4(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_5(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_6(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_7(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_8(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_9(...)  PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_10(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_11(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_12(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_13(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, _3, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_14(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, _2, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_15(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER(_1, __VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_ARG_AT_16(...) PP_EXPAND(PP_ARG_POPER( __VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: hi, i will not use this code, i asked this question, because i want to study this technique of preprocessor accoss this title, thanks a lot

Comment: Is this C or C++? Pick one. In C++ there are more robust techniques you can use instead of macros.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/max_d.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11, `std::max` works with `initializer_list`, so you may use

```
std::max({40, 31, 42, 13, 4, 25, 16, 27});
```

And if you really want `MAX(p1, p2, p3)` syntax, you may do:

```
#define MAX(...) std::max({__VA_ARGS__})
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question contains a half of the answer - you can build `min`/`max` macros with the variable arguments number using the technique shown in `PP_ARG_COUNT` macro (as with original code the number of arguments will have the limit, but you can choose it).

Here is the sample code (up to 4 arguments):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __START(op, A, B, C, D, N, ...) __ARGS_##N(op, A, B, C, D)
#define __ARGS_1(op, A, B, C, D) A
#define __ARGS_2(op, A, B, C, D) __##op(A, B)
#define __ARGS_3(op, A, B, C, D) __##op(A, __##op(B, C))
#define __ARGS_4(op, A, B, C, D) __##op(__##op(A, B), __##op(C, D))


#define __MIN(A, B) ((A) < (B) ? (A) : (B))
#define __MAX(A, B) ((A) > (B) ? (A) : (B))

#define min(...) __START(MIN, __VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define max(...) __START(MAX, __VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)

int main(void)
{
   printf("min(1) -> %d\n\n", min(1));
   printf("min(1.5, 2) -> %lf\n", min(1.5,2));
   printf("min(3, 2, 1.5) -> %lf\n", min(3,2,1.5));
   printf("min(1, 2, 3, 4) -> %d\n", min(1,2,3,4));
   printf("min(2, 3, 4, 1) -> %d\n\n", min(2,3,4,1));

   printf("max(2.5, 2.0) -> %lf\n", max(2.5, 2.0));
   printf("max(3, 2, 3.5) -> %lf\n", max(3, 2, 3.5));
   printf("max(1, 2, 3, 4) -> %d\n", max(1, 2, 3, 4));
   printf("max(2, 3, 4, 1) -> %d\n", max(2, 3, 4, 1));

   return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run the program you will get the following output:

```
min(1) -> 1

min(1.5, 2) -> 1.500000
min(3, 2, 1.5) -> 1.500000
min(1, 2, 3, 4) -> 1
min(2, 3, 4, 1) -> 1

max(2.5, 2.0) -> 2.500000
max(3, 2, 3.5) -> 3.500000
max(1, 2, 3, 4) -> 4
max(2, 3, 4, 1) -> 4
```

How it works. The `__START` macro takes the following arguments:

- `op` - the macro name (without preceding double underscore) which does the necessary operation with just two arguments
- `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` - these arguments will receive the arguments of the `min`/`max` and possibly some dummy ones if the number of `min`/`max` arguments was less then the maximum (4 in this sample code).
- `N` - the number of `min`/`max` arguments.
- `...` - some other dummy arguments.

`__START` will expand to one of the `__ARGS_1`..`__ARGS_4` depending of arguments number. The arguments number is obtained by adding `4, 3, 2, 1` arguments invoking `__START` macro:

```
#define min(...) __START(MIN, __VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

So, if you invoke for instance `min(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)` it will expand to (I added arguments names in comments):

```
__START(/*op=*/ MIN, /*A=*/ 1.5, /*B=*/ 2.5, /*C=*/ 3.5, /*D=*/ 4, /*N=*/ 3, 2, 1)
```

The `__START` will then expand to `__ARGS_3` and the following expansions are trivial.
Now it is clearly seen how arguments number "counted" and how it works. You can easily implement the same macros with other functionality and increase maximum number of arguments, for example `sum`:

```
#define __SUM(A, B) ((A)+(B))
#define sum(...) __START(SUM, __VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Thought it is not as useful as `min`/`max` ones.

P.S. If you use Visual C++ you will need to add some workaround (like `PP_EXPAND` in the first post) to overcome VC++ preprocessor bug, [see for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754654/why-this-pp-arg-count-macro-need-a-pp-expand). I used GCC, it does not need one.

Answer (score 2):

There is C++ STL algorithm to do the same:

> [max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/).
>
> [min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/)

Starts using these instead of writing the macro to achieve this:

```
 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 int* min = std::min_element(arr, arr+5);
 int* max = std::max_element(arr,arr+5);
 std::cout<<"min:"<<*min<<"max:"<<*max<<std::endl;
```

Comment: hi, i will not use this code, i asked this question, because i want to  study this technique of preprocessor, thanks a lot...

Comment: @Hikari: There is almost no need to write the MACRO in pure C++. These STL algorithm would be as efficient(almost) as the MACRO. You may also use inline concept to achieve MACRO type behaviour. So you should study these concept instead of MACRO..The choice is yours :)

Comment: @tmp It could still be an interesting learning exercise. We can't read Hikari's mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), you can implement it like this:

```
#define MAX_FOLD(s, state, elem) BOOST_PP_MAX(state, elem) 
#define MAX(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(MAX_FOLD, 0, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Because the preprocessor doesn't directly support comparison during expansion, It is a lot of work to implement all this from scratch. Using techniques [here](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms), you can implement a counter and a while loop construct. With that you can implement subtraction, which will allow you to implement less than(or greater than), which is needed for `MAX`. Then with another `while` you can do a fold over the varidiac arguments.

Finally, there are some limitations to doing all this in the preprocessor. The preprocessr is not entirely turing complete. So in the boost example, you would be limited to values from 0 to 256(this is entirely a boost limitation, if you do it yourself you could raise that limitation). Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be better to write a varidiac function for max:

```
template<class T, class U>
T max(T x, T y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

template<class... Ts>
T max(T x, Ts... xs)
{
    return max(x, max(xs...)); 
}
```